# Notification using Ajax polling in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, long-polling

how we can achieve Facebook like notification using ajax long polling in codeigniter. I m new in ajax, so plz suggest me

Comment: check this: http://pusher.com/

Comment: i saw that website.. its good.. but whenever any changes in my database(MySql) it should give notification. so how we can achieve

Comment: read the documentation, you can send push through php. https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php